# Cannot figure out how to render a new page in express

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I have this `ships.js` in my routes folder:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET Ships page. */
router.get('/ships', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('ships', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And I have these to statements in my `app.js`:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var ships = require('./routes/users');
```

and

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/ships', ships);
app.use('/users', users);
```

However if I navigate to `localhost:3000/ships` I receive the following message:

**respond with a resource**

Sorry have read the docs, just not to snazzy with express.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in you `app` module:

1.Invalid `require` call for `ships` route:

```
var ships = require('./routes/users'); <--
// should be:
var ships = require('./routes/ships');
```

2.Invalid `router` using in `app.use`:

```
app.use('/ships', ships);
// should be:
app.use(ships); // and the same for others
```